# How to overlay WFS output in GML format on a googlemap api v3 using GeoXML3

Tags: google-maps, wfs

I would like to overlay a polygon layer on Google map API V3  from a WFS output file  in GML2 format from a remote WFS server. No other output format is available in the WFS server.

Is it possible to do this using GeoXML3 ?

It would be great if some can give me a demo link  which using a GML2.

Answer (score 1):

GeoXML is for processing KML in the browser. GML is not KML, so that won't work. You can overlay GML on Google Maps API v3 using OpenLayers. I can't find a demo link, but here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>Google Maps API v3 and WFS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/google.css" type="text/css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/style.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&amp;sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/lib/Firebug/firebug.js"></script>
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var map;

        function init() {
            OpenLayers.ProxyHost= "proxy.cgi?url=";
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

            var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                "Google Physical",
                {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}
            );

            var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
            renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;

            var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("States", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                        featureType: "states",
                        featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
                    }),
                    renderers: renderer
                });

            map.addLayers([gphy, wfs]);

            // Google.v3 uses EPSG:900913 as projection, so we have to
            // transform our coordinates
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-98.5795, 39.828175).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                map.getProjectionObject()
            ), 3);

        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <h1 id="title">Google (v3) Layer Example + WFS</h1>
        <p id="shortdesc">
            Demonstrate use the Google Maps v3 API with WFS.
        </p>
        <div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

A couple of caveats:

- the script pulls the stylesheets and OpenLayer.js from the OpenLayers
  site, you will want to change that to your local install of
  OpenLayers
- you will need to set up a proxy since you are requesting GML from a
  site outside your domain, please see
  http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost
- the mapping portion (init()) is often written as a separate
  javascript file, but it's included here to be explicit

Comment: Thank you Sophia for your answer. I think here we are using Openlayers not Googlemap API V3. I am using Openlayers to pull the WFS GML data, Now I want to Overlay this Polygon over googlemaps API V3.

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.dyasdesigns.com/geoxml/) This is Google Map API V2 and I could not see a good example.  Here is another link  to a presentation( search for google_wfs_arch in google the first lik).Unfortunately their demo links are not working.  I think It is possible  but still looking for a good example which uses real GLM2 from WFS.